# Check if each element contains a another particular element

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<div class="main">
   <div class="sub"></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
   <div class="sub"></div>
</div>

<div class="main">
   <div class="another"></div> <!-- Attention: This div does not have .sub -->
</div>

<div class="main">
   <div class="sub"></div>
</div>
```

How to check that there one div.main which does not contain div.sub?

My code below seems to check only for the first div.main

```
if ($('.main .sub')[0]) {
    console.log('All div.main contain div.sub');
}
else {
    console.log('Some div.main which does not contain div.sub');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can

```
if($('.main:not(:has(.sub))').length == 0){
    console.log('all contains sub')
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zZxqn/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.main').each(function() {
    if ($(this).children('.sub').length > 0) {
         console.log("yes");
    } else {
         console.log("no");
    }
});
```